# How to increase timeout of EC2 instance for http request

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We are getting 504 timedout issue whenever the response time exceeds 60s.

EC2 instance is timed out in 60 second. Is there any way to to increase the time-out time configuration in EC2 instance?

We tried with configuration changes in server.xml.. The results remain same.

Comment: please specify what webserver you're using. most likely it is a max_client setting you have,

Comment: using apache tomcat as webserver. It is on centos os.

Comment: keep in mind most browsers timeout is set to 60 seconds, so might not be on the server but client side

Answer (score 0):

By default ELB has a default connection timeout of 60 seconds. This is probably what's causing you grief. You can increase this to up to 4000 seconds, however one must ask why your application takes more than 60 seconds to respond to a web request in the first place.

Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html).

Comment: We tried with changing the ELB setting, tomcat server configuration.. issue remained same.. we are using centos os.

60 seconds to respond is due to load testing, we are performing on this server